# Rails multi-tenant data separation: around_filter w/ default_scope vs handling in authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi-tenant app in rails. I've decided not to do a separate table for each tenant like in the appartment gem.

I've decided that I can either do an around_filter in my application controller that puts a default_scope on everything, but I also thought that maybe it would be easy enough to do via permissions in the authorization gem I'm using.

The latter seems simpler, so I'm tempted to go with it. But I don't see it being recommended anywhere so I'm wondering if there's maybe a major security hole I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems sensible to use authorization gem. If implemented correctly, there should be no serious security hole at application level, so go for it. (If you use CanCan, there was already a question on this on StackOverflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570671/authorization-gem-for-a-multi-tenancy-application))

Note that if you are concerned about security more than anything else, you should have gone for separate tables, schemas or even databases. But hopefully you have already analyzed the possible choices :) Anyway, here is an [interesting article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) about multi-tenant architecture with lots of useful thoughts and hints.

Comment: I've actually already seen that MSDN article, super helpful :)

Actually, the reason I'm using only one set of tables is because I felt that for my first rails app, it's just way simpler, and it'll allow for easier integration of different gems.